# Что такое декоратор? Почему именно функция внутри функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Огромная просьба, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему декоратор - это именно функция внутри функции?
Почитал несколько статей, но нигде не вижу ответа конкретно на этот вопрос.

```
def func_decor2(some_func):
    print('Что-то делаем ДО')
    some_func()
    print('Что-то делаем после')
```

Чем не декоратор?
Единственное, что приходит на ум по использованию дополнительной функции внутри - удобная передача аргументов, если наша `some_func()` будет требовать атрибуты.
Огромная просьба внятно и чётко объяснить, как именно устроен декоратор и почему именно так, когда внутри декоратора обязательно должна быть еще одна функция-"обёртка".
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Декоратор — это функция, которая **возвращает новую функцию**. Ваша же функция ничего не возвращает, а просто сразу выполняет some_func

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, но если коротко, как сам понимаю: декоратор - не обязательно функция внутри функции. Декоратор позволяет расширять и изменять поведение разных вызываемых объектов (включая функции, но можно и классы, и методы). Он позволяет избежать модификации этих объектов. @ - всего лишь удобный синтаксис для декоратора. Если внутри него нет другого объекта, то он просто не нужен. И он сам - обертка, никакой обертки внутри не нужно в общем случае. P.s. А "чоткими" бывают только пацаны, объяснения пока ещё чёткие:-)

Comment: Кстати, по теории читать лучше университетские учебники, рекомендованные Министерством, а не только статьи (в России, как минимум, но полагаю, что аналогична ситуация с Украиной и Беларусью, может, и с рядом других соседних стран).

Comment: @Сергей Рад, что Вы заметили "чотко", мне нравится именно так писать, забавно выглядит)
Не подскажите пример подобных учебников? Полагаю, что многие из них уже не актуальны.

Comment: Чернышов, нопремер. "Асновы праграммиравания на Петоне". С сидьмой гловы там ни ах, но тиорея пакатит (забавна до ужаса такая грамматика, бугага).

Comment: @Сергей Это уже слишком вырвиглазно, Вы уже утрируете) 1 слово среди нескольких предложений сравнивать с этим - уже и не смешно и непонятно для чего.

Comment: Я слэдую вашиму: "мне нравится именно так писать, забавно выглядит". Есть правыла языка, если же наченать от ных отхадыт дла забавнасты, то у каждого будут сваи понятея о забавном, бугага. Но эта уже off-topic, четайте учебник, там савсем нэ забавна, а палезна. (Это один из приёмов логики, называется "доведение до абсурда" - хорошо показывает неувязки в логических обоснованиях оппонента).

Answer (score 1):

По большому счету декоратор это способ избежать многократного дублирования кода.

Предположим у вас есть код из 10 миллионов строк, и 100 однострочных функций которые вызываются в 1000 разных частях кода.
И вдруг вам понадобилось добавить в эти функции какой-то функционал 'Что-то делаем ДО' и 'Что-то делаем после', который занимает 5000 срок.

Что вы будете делать, искать эти 1000 строк кода вызова функций, и для каждого вызова прописывать 'Что-то делаем ДО' и 'Что-то делаем после' 1000 раз, добавляя дополнительные 5 миллионов строк кода?

Или в каждую из 100 функций добавлять эти дополнительные 5000 строк кода, превращая 100 строк кода функций в 500 тысяч + 100 строк?
А если потом вам надо будет отключить этот функционал для части функций, будете искать и удалять эти тысячи строк, сколько это займет времени, останется ли читабельным ваш код?

Или вы можете сделать декоратор, и вместо дополнительных 500 тысяч строк в вашем подходе, добавить всего 5 тысяч строк самого декоратора + 100 строк
для декорирования функций.
Более того, можно гибко управлять поведением декоратора, например через аргументы декоратора, либо вовсе отключить его, удалив лишь одну строчку кода @dec_arg() над функцией, либо вообще декорируя функцию по месту вызова, как ниже для func_2

```
DecEnable = True  # глобальная переменная, которая управляет поведением декоратора dec_arg, позволяет централизовано отключить дополнительный код всех декораторов, задекорированных без указания аргумента enable, т.е. как как @dec_arg()

def dec_arg(enable=DecEnable):
    def decor(func):  # тут 5000 строк дополнительного функционала, которые располагаются не внутри каждой из функций, а в одном месте, только здесь
        def wrap(*a, **k):
            if enable:
                print(func.__name__, f'Что-то делаем ДО {(a, k)}')
                try: return func(*a, **k)
                finally: print(func.__name__, f'Что-то делаем после {(a, k)}')
            else: return func(*a, **k)
        return wrap
    return decor

# ниже код из 10 миллионов строк, и 100 однострочных функций
@dec_arg(enable=False)  # поведение декоратора управляется из аргумента декоратора enable=False, в данном случае дополнительный код декоратора отключен
def func_1(a):
    print(a)

def func_2(a): # эта функция вообще не задекорирована
    print(a)

@dec_arg()  # () - без аргументов - поведение декоратора управляется глобальной переменной DecEnable, можно отключить дополнительный код всех декораторов, просто установив ее в False
def func_99(a):
    print(a)

@dec_arg()  # вместо 5000 дополнительных строк кода, мы добавили только одну, весь код находится в декораторе
def func_100(a):
    print(a)
# вызов функций в 1000 разных частях кода
func_1(1)  # вызов декорированной функции, но тут дополнительный код декоратора отключен в аргументе декорирования
dec_arg(enable=True)(func_2)(2)  # декорирование функции по месту ее вызова, независимо от состояния DecEnable, дополнительный код декоратора выполнится, т.к. enable=True
func_2(3)  # а тут вызов не задекорированной функции
func_99(4)  # вызов декорированной функции, поведение декоратора управляется глобальной переменной DecEnable
func_100(5)  # вызов декорированной функции, поведение декоратора управляется глобальной переменной DecEnable
```

Для этого и нужна функция обертка внутри декоратора, чтобы можно было декорировать множество функций одним и тем-же декоратором @dec_arg(), тем самым добавляя в них новую функциональность, но не добавляя внутри функций ни строчки лишнего кода

Answer (score 1):

То что вы написали есть декоратор, который декорирует это конкретный вызов функции. Чтобы его использовать в коде, надо менять код: если вы где-то вызывали оригинальную функцию теперь надо сменить её имя на декорированную.

А если вы используете декоратор в стандартном смысле, вы меняете поведение всех вызовов функции везде где она упомянута по имени.

Пример:

```
def f():
    print("I'm f!")


def g():
    f()
    f()
```

Чтобы декорировать `f` и воспользоваться новой версией надо написать:

```
def decorated(f):
    print("before f")
    f()
    print("after f")


def g2():
    decorated(f)
    decorated(f)


g2()
```

Пришлось заменить `g` на `g2`. Если мы собирались использовать декоратор для отладки, в этом мало смысла, надо переписать весь отлаживаемый код.

Вот вариант с обычным декоратором:

```
def decorated(f):

    def ff():
        print("before f")
        f()
        print("after f")

    return ff


f = decorated(f)
g()
```

Куда удобнее, `g` переписывать не надо, поведение `f` изменилось по всему коду, хотя сам код остался прежним.

В последнем варианте становится ясно почему нужно возвращать функцию - то что возвращает декоратор займёт место оригинальной функции и должно вести себя как функция.

Answer (score 1):

попробую объяснить как я сам понимаю декораторы на примере вашего примера:

```
def func_decor2(some_func):
    print('Что-то делаем ДО')
    some_func()
    print('Что-то делаем после')
```

по сути здесь вы добавили некий функционал к функции sum_func(), но представьте, что вы добавляете этот функционал к уже существующей функции, которая в разных частях вашего кода вызывается много раз. теперь для того чтобы новый функционал реализовался вам надо в вашем коде заменить все вызовы функции sum_func() на func_decor2(some_func).

в случае же использования декоратора-обертки ничего переписывать не надо, пишите декоратор, обертываете им функцию sum_func() и теперь при каждом ее вызове будет срабатывать декоратор.

```
def func_decor2(some_func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print('Что-то делаем ДО')
        some_func(*args,**kwargs)
        print('Что-то делаем после')
    return wrapper

@func_decor2()
def some_func():
    pass
```

для себя я понял так, что если у меня простой код и мне не сложно что-то добавить и поменять в работе функций, то и декораторы мне не нужны